# Convert a Log file to JSON file

Tags: json, powershell, logging, text-parsing

I would like to convert a log file to JSON format.

The content of the Log file is as below:

```
2021-07-13T14:32:00.197904  DDD client=10.4.35.4
2021-07-13T14:32:00.271923  BBB from=<josh.josh@test.com>
2021-07-13T14:32:01.350434  CCC from=<rob.roder@test.com>
2021-07-13T14:32:01.417904  DDD message-id=<1-2-3-a-a@A1>
2021-07-13T14:32:01.586494  DDD from=<Will.Smith@test.com>
2021-07-13T14:32:02.643101  DDD to=<Will.Smith@test.com>
2021-07-13T14:32:02.712803  AAA client=10.1.35.2
2021-07-13T14:32:03.832661  BBB client=2021:8bd::98e7:2e04:f94s
2021-07-13T14:32:03.920297  DDD status=sent
```

However the problem that occurs is that I need to match the IDs for each line to export to JSON that looks like:

```
  {
   "time": {
      "start": "2021-07-13T14:32:01.417904",
      "duration": "0:00:02.502393"
    },
    "sessionid": "DDD",
    "client": "10.4.35.4",
    "messageid": "<1-2-3-a-a@A1>",
    "address": {
        "from": "<Will.Smith@test.com>",
        "to": "<Will.Smith@test.com>"
    },
    "status": "sent"
  }
]
```

Next step is to import this data to analysis tool which only acceps JSON format. I've tried this with powershell and python, but got nowhere near the expected output.
The problems along the way:
How to link each row by session?
How to count 1st and last session duration?
How to link each session 3rd column results and how to convert them to json?

I would really appreciate any help, links, studies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may do something similar to the following:

```
Get-Content a.log | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^(?<time>\S+)\s+(?<sessionid>\w+)\s+(?<key>[^=]+)=(?<data>.*)$') {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            time = $matches.time
            sessionid = $matches.sessionid
            key = $matches.key
            data = $matches.data
        } 
    }
} | Group sessionid | Foreach-Object {
    $jsonTemplate = [pscustomobject]@{
        time = [pscustomobject]@{ start = ''; duration = '' }
        sessionid = ''
        client = '' 
        messageid = ''
        address = [pscustomobject]@{from = ''; to = ''}
        status = ''
    }
    $start = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'message-id').time
    $end = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'status').time -as [datetime]
    $jsonTemplate.time.start = $start
    $jsonTemplate.time.duration = ($end - ($start -as [datetime])).ToString()
    $jsonTemplate.sessionid = $_.Name
    $jsonTemplate.client = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'client').data
    $jsonTemplate.messageid = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'message-id').data
    $jsonTemplate.address.from = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'from').data
    $jsonTemplate.address.to = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'to').data
    $jsonTemplate.status = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'status').data
    [regex]::Unescape(($jsonTemplate | convertTo-Json))
}
```

The general steps that are happening are the following:

1. Parse the log file to separate data elements
2. Group by sessionid to easily identify all event entries belonging to the session id
3. Create a custom object that contains the schema that'll easily convert to the desired JSON format.
4. The regex unescape is to remove the unicode escape codes for the `<` and `>` characters.

---

The `$matches` automatic variable updates when the `-match` operation returns `$true`. Since we are using named capture groups in the regex expression, capture groups are accessible as keys in the `$matches` hashtable.

---

**Caveats:**

- Assumes sessionid only has one session per id.
- Missing session data shows up as null in JSON format.

---

Alternative solutions may use `ConvertFrom-String` when reading the file. It is just simpler for me personally to do regex matching instead.

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement, which enables fast line-by-line processing with its `-File` parameter:

- A nested (ordered) [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) is used to compile session-specific information across lines.
- The [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) is used to split each line into fields, and to split the last field into property name and value.

Note:

- The calculation of the session duration assumes that the *first* line for a given session ID marks the start of the session, and a line with a `status=` value the end.

```sh
$sessions = [ordered] @{}
switch -File file.log { # process file line by line
  default {
    $timestamp, $sessionId, $property = -split $_ # split the line into fields
    $name, $value = $property -split '=', 2       # split the property into name an value
    if ($session = $sessions.$sessionId) { # entry for session ID already exists
      $session.$name = $value
      # end of session? calculate the duration
      if ($name -eq 'status') { $session.time.duration = ([datetime] $timestamp - [datetime] $session.time.start).ToString() }
    } 
    else { # create new entry for this session ID
      $sessions.$sessionId = [ordered] @{
        $name = $value
        time = [ordered] @{
          start = $timestamp
          duration = $null
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}

# Convert the hashtable to JSON
$sessions | ConvertTo-Json
```