# How do I exclude a group from the output once a group has been compiled in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, group

I am using previous code ([Convert a Log file to JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68394277/convert-a-log-file-to-json-file)) to parse a log file into JSON. However, part of the fields within some groups are not available and appear in the groupings in the output as "null". How would I exclude an entire group if one of the fields contains null or incomplete group fields?

```
| Group sessionid | Foreach-Object {
$jsonTemplate = [pscustomobject]@{
    time = [pscustomobject]@{ start = ''; duration = '' }
    group1 = ''
    host1 = '' 
    title1 = ''
    address = [pscustomobject]@{from = ''; to = ''}
    situation = ''
}
$start = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'title1').time
$end = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'situation').time -as [datetime]
$jsonTemplate.time.start = $begin
$jsonTemplate.time.duration = ($end - ($start -as [datetime])).ToString()
$jsonTemplate.group1 = $_.Name
$jsonTemplate.host1 = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'host1').data
$jsonTemplate.title1 = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'title1').data
$jsonTemplate.address.sender = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'sender').data
$jsonTemplate.address.reciever = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'reciever').data
$jsonTemplate.situation = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'situation').data
[regex]::Unescape(($jsonTemplate | convertTo-Json))
```

Comment: What in the world is going on here: `[regex]::Unescape(($jsonTemplate | convertTo-Json))`?!

Comment: EDIT* I do know, this part of the code was pulled from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68394277/convert-a-log-file-to-json-file and it is being used to remove the < and > that export out.

Comment: `[regex]::Unescape()` is the complement to `[regex]::Escape()`, has nothing to do with JSON. Can you show us the code you used to parse/obtain the logs in the first place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68394277/convert-a-log-file-to-json-file

Answer (score 0):

Not the most beautiful piece of code, but something like this should work

```
If(($_.Name -ne $Null -or $_.Name -ne "") -or (($_.Group | where key -eq 'client').data -ne $Null -or ($_.Group | where key -eq 'client').data -ne "") -or (($_.Group | where key -eq 'message-id').data -ne $Null -or ($_.Group | where key -eq 'message-id').data -ne "") -or (($_.Group | where key -eq 'from').data -ne $Null -or ($_.Group | where key -eq 'from').data -ne "") -or (($_.Group | where key -eq 'to').data -ne $Null -or ($_.Group | where key -eq 'to').data -ne "") -or (($_.Group | where key -eq 'status').data -ne $Null -or ($_.Group | where key -eq 'status').data -ne "") -or )
{
    $jsonTemplate.time.start = $start
    $jsonTemplate.time.duration = ($end - ($start -as [datetime])).ToString()
    $jsonTemplate.sessionid = $_.Name
    $jsonTemplate.client = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'client').data
    $jsonTemplate.messageid = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'message-id').data
    $jsonTemplate.address.from = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'from').data
    $jsonTemplate.address.to = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'to').data
    $jsonTemplate.status = ($_.Group | where key -eq 'status').data
    [regex]::Unescape(($jsonTemplate | convertTo-Json))
}
```

It checks each for null or empty

Comment: Also throwing an error:
+ ...  -ne $Null -or ($_.Group | where key -eq 'status').data -ne "") -or )
+                                                                        ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-or' operator.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Sorry, I don't have data to test it.

```
| $Groups = Group-Object -Property sessionid

# Create an empty array to fill
$Array = @()

# Loop over each group
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
   # Create an object
   $jsonTemplate = [pscustomobject]@{
      time = [pscustomobject]@{ start = ''; duration = '' }
      sessionId = ''
      client = ''
      messageId = ''
      address = [pscustomobject]@{from = ''; to = ''}
      status = ''
   }

   # Get the group's data
   $Data = $Group.Group
   
   # messageId
   $messageId = $Data | Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'messageId'}
   if ($messageId) {
      $jsonTemplate.messageId = $messageId.data
      [datetime]$start = $messageId.Time
   } else {continue}

   # status
   $status = $Data | Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'status'}
   if ($status) {
      $jsonTemplate.status = $status.data
      [datetime]$end = $status.Time
   } else {continue}

   # sessionid
   if ($Group.Name) {$jsonTemplate.sessionid = $Group.Name} else {continue}

   # client
   $client = $Data | Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'client'}
   if ($client) {$jsonTemplate.client = $client.data} else {continue}

   # from
   $from = $Data | Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'from'}
   if ($from) {$jsonTemplate.address.from = $from.data} else {continue}

   # to
   $to = $Data | Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'to'}
   if ($to) {$jsonTemplate.address.to = $to.data} else {continue}

   # Add to array
   $Array += $jsonTemplate
}

# Convert the array
$json = $Array | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

# Do stuff with the json
[regex]::Unescape($json)
```

Comment: Getting the following error: + | $Groups = Group-Object -Property sessionid
+ ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement